How to download ffmpeg utilities into Python venv with pip or manual way for torchaudio
torchaudio requiring avutil and other binary dll files
Source : https://pytorch.org/audio/2.3.0/installation.html
However they given example only for Anaconda
I am not using Anaconda but I am using Python 3.10.11 pip venv
I can't find these DLL files anywhere
How can I find and install them into Python venv?
Since I can't find, I am getting below error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\queueing.py", line 625, in process_events
    response = await route_utils.call_process_api(
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\route_utils.py", line 322, in call_process_api
    output = await app.get_blocks().process_api(
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 2047, in process_api
    result = await self.call_function(
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1594, in call_function
    prediction = await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(  # type: ignore
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 56, in run_sync
    return await get_async_backend().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 2505, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 1005, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\utils.py", line 869, in wrapper
    response = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py", line 116, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\gradio_demo.py", line 60, in video_to_audio
    clip_frames, sync_frames, duration = load_video(video, duration)
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\mmaudio\eval_utils.py", line 178, in load_video
    reader = StreamingMediaDecoder(video_path)
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\venv\lib\site-packages\torio\io\_streaming_media_decoder.py", line 526, in __init__
    self._be = ffmpeg_ext.StreamingMediaDecoder(os.path.normpath(src), format, option)
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\venv\lib\site-packages\torio\_extension\utils.py", line 25, in __getattr__
    self._import_once()
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\venv\lib\site-packages\torio\_extension\utils.py", line 39, in _import_once
    self.module = self.import_func()
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\venv\lib\site-packages\torio\_extension\utils.py", line 143, in _init_ffmpeg
    ext = _find_ffmpeg_extension(ffmpeg_vers)
  File "R:\MMAudio_v1\MMAudio\venv\lib\site-packages\torio\_extension\utils.py", line 122, in _find_ffmpeg_extension
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Failed to intialize FFmpeg extension. Tried versions: ['6', '5', '4', '']. Enable DEBUG logging to see more details about the error.


Note that ffmpeg itself does not need to be installed in the virtual environment. ffmpeg is not written in Python and as far as I know is not packaged for installation with pip from PyPI. You will need to figure out the best way to install ffmpeg for your own operating system according to your own requirements and expectations. Using the conda ecosystem is one good solution. Otherwise, I guess: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html.

From my quick research, you need to place ffmpeg shared libraries to enable the extension. You can try downloading Gyan's release page and download a version which is "full-shared". If the pytorch does not support the latest v7.x, you need to hunt down the v6 full-shared release. You then need to unzip the files somewhere in the system path or python path.
Here is an alternate way to download: you can use my ffmpeg-downloader package
pip install ffmpeg-downloader

Then run
ffdl list

to list all available ffmpeg versions.
To install the latest (v7.1) with shared dlls
ffdl install --add-path 7@full-shared

--add-path option adds the install path to your system path. You only need to add this once. Once installed, you need to restart the terminal before running Python.
If pytorch does not support v7.1 and need to downgrade run
ffdl install -U 6@full-shared

This will install the last v6 full-shared version.
Hope this helps
